# Minecraft log in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I made some worlds on Minecraft but I want to sign into my account. Will that get rid of the worlds I made on Steve or will they go on the account?

Comment: So did you use the free-trial then?

Comment: Are you on Bedrock or Java?

Answer (score 1):

The worlds you make in Minecraft are always saved directly to your hard drive. They should show up regardless of the account you sign into because Minecraft reads from its AppData/.minecraft/Worlds folder, and not a specific user world folder.

Basically, all worlds on the drive show up in Minecraft.